# Netbeans Project Configuration When Using Maven Project

Tags: maven, netbeans

does anyone know how to configure a project using maven?  My issue is that when I create a project by doing New->Maven->Enterprise Application Project, I don't get all the IDE helpers that are available when I create the equivalent project using the default (which is an Ant project) option by doing New->Java EE->Enterprise Application Project.

If I go to the generated Main.java in the default project I get the option to use ALT+Insert which brings up useful Java EE code insertion helpers such as "Call Enterprise Bean", "Use Database", etc.  These are not available in the maven generated project.

Looking at the default project's files, the project.xml contains this entry "org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.clientproject", which I believe is the IDEs instruction to generate the Java EE helpers for this project.

The maven projects project files, pox.xml and nb-configuration.xml, haven't got this entry.  The nb-configuration.xml file does however have these entries:

```
<org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_j2eeVersion>1.7</org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_j2eeVersion>
    <org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server>gfv3ee6</org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server>
```

which must have something to do with the project setup.  They don't give Java EE helpers though.  Anyone have any idea how to add something like the defaults projects "org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.clientproject" to the maven project to get the helpers working??

Any help appreciated.